# When asking a question, when should you use "may"?

Tags: american-english

When asking a question like "May you print a copy of that for me?", when should you use "may" or "could"?

Comment: First, notice, you're not asking a question -- you don't want somebody to tell you how probable their copying is, you want somebody to **do** the copying. In other words, you're making a request, disguised as a question. Second, in cases of such indirect requests, _may_ is not used. _Would_ or _will_ or _could_ or _can_ are frequently used, but not _may_. _May_ has many uses, but this is not one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you *could* have easily found the answer to this on Google, but the recap is that **may** is used primarily (though with diminishing frequency, at least in the US) for permission and **can** (and its past tense **could**) are used for mere ability.

In this case, you would use *may* if you were asking if they had permission to print you a copy. This seems unlikely, unless there is an arbiter of printing that must be consulted.

I think you're looking for **could** here. You want to know if they have the physical, mental, spatial, temporal, etc., ability to print you a copy.

Adding some detail to your question will make an answer more clear, but I hope this points you in the right direction. You're almost certainly looking for could/can in this case.

Comment: Wouldn't it be "can" since it matches "print"? "Can you print me...?" versus "Could you have printed me...?"

Comment: @MrHen I think both would be acceptable. Most definitions I've seen of "could" include at least one entry pertaining to its use as a word of possibility or cordiality. As long as conditional and perfect tenses aren't confused, I think using "could" is acceptable in this case.

Comment: Any examples? This is new information to me. I couldn't find this use in ESL books. I could think of possible scenarios but I don't want speculations when I want to learn. So any examples please? ------
"Could you have printed me...?" =?= "As long as conditional and perfect tenses aren't confused, I think using "could" is acceptable in this case."

Answer (score -1):

In this type of construction, *[may](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/may?q=may#may)* means *is it permissible*. Unless you are asking whether the rules allow the copying, *[can](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/can?q=can)* or *[could](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/could?q=could)* should be used. Both of those terms mean *is it possible*.

The purists would make the following distinctions:

> May I go home now? [*Have the charges been dropped allowing me to leave the police station?*]
>
> Can I go home now? [*Has the bridge been repaired and is the road open?*]

In the first instance, colloquial speech often allows the substitution of *can* for *may* when *permission* is the criterion. In the latter case, you would not use *may* when actual ability is at issue.

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: @sgroves Beats me.